# how to unchecked button when a dialog popup?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

i need to popup a dialog, but everytime when the dialog popup, there is  certain button is always checked, no matter how i set it's attribute before start up that always is checked, can anyone tell me reason?

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Demo(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.export_bn = QPushButton('export')
        self.search_bn = QPushButton('search')
        layout.addStretch(1)
        layout.addWidget(self.export_bn)
        layout.addWidget(self.search_bn)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(QTextEdit('Test'))
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        #unchecked this button not working when start a window
        self.export_bn.setChecked(False)


app = QApplication([])
demo = Demo()
demo.show()
app.exec()
```

---

The export button is checked, i want to no button checked when dialog popup.

[image: "sample"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like auto-default button behavior.

From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#default-prop) for the `autoDefault` property:

> In some GUI styles a default button is drawn with an extra frame around it, up to 3 pixels or more.

and

> This property's default is true for buttons that have a QDialog parent; otherwise it defaults to false.

The `QDialog` automatically becomes the buttons' `parent` when you call `setLayout`, so the `autoDefault` property will be `True` for both buttons.

So, instead of using `self.export_bn.setChecked(False)`, you can do this:

```
self.export_bn.setAutoDefault(False)
self.search_bn.setAutoDefault(False)
```

Comment: hi, your method work fine!